# react-native-document-scanner-plugin How do I store the url string returned by the library on the server?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, file

```
const scanDocument = async () => {
    // start the document scanner
    const {scannedImages} = await DocumentScanner.scanDocument();
    if (scannedImages === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    scannedImages.forEach(image => {
      formData.append('files', image);
    });

    fileUploadTrigger({formData: formData}).then(() => {
      setAddFileSheetState(false);
    });
  };
```

With this code, the url string received from the plugin is processed. fileUploadTrigger is a swr mutate trigger. The image file selected by DocumentPicker is saved using the fileUploadTrigger function.

However, if you put the data returned by DocumentScanner.scanDocument(); into formData and send it to the server, the server cannot detect the file, and DocumentScanner returns the following result.

```
console.log(formData)
LOG  {"_parts": [["files", "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.temp/files/Pictures/DOCUMENT_SCAN_0_20231002_0105125384416324539389181.jpg"]]}
```

I think I need to change string[] to something suitable, but I don't know how to do that, any advice would be appreciated.